# Unity Помогите разобраться со скриптом

Tags: c#, unity3d

Недавно столкнулся с проблемой пересечения нескольких Scroll Rect'ов. К сожалению, ответа на данном сайте и его западном брате не получил. Но по счастливой случайности нашёл интересную тему на форуме Unity, которая, по идее, должна бы решать мою проблему: [Форум Unity](https://forum.unity.com/threads/nested-scrollrect.268551/)

Оттуда был взят предложенный [скрипт](https://forum.unity.com/threads/nested-scrollrect.268551/#post-1906953) и, судя по отзывам, он для многих решил подобную проблему.

У самого меня не удалось решить проблему. Прошу вас помочь разобраться. :)

На том же сайте Unity, но уже в разделах вопрос-ответ нашёл связанный [вопрос, в ответе к которому указали](http://answers.unity.com/answers/1146970/view.html), что данный скрипт надо помещать на дочерние Scroll Rect'ы. Однако, ничего в моем случае не меняется. В чем ошибка? :)

Так выглядит мой убогонький учебный проект, на котором я пытаюсь реализовать данный скрипт: [image: В режиме редактирования]

Скрипт помещался на Page 1,2,3, как и указано в вопросах-ответах. Однако, ничего не меняется. В качестве контента выбирались по-разному элементы Page 2(то, что и надо проматывать в двух направлениях).

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чём мой промах?

Скролл по горизонтали всего контента реализуется при помощи UI Extensions Horizontal Scroll Snap.
При запуске выглядит как-то так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а какого именно поведения вы хотите добиться от ваших панелей? Чтобы при движении пальца по вертикали - скролилось текущее окно, а по горизонтали окна переключались?

Comment: @M.Green, Именно такого